# Weird table repeating when displaying mysql results

Tags: php, html-table

There's nothing wrong with the result itself.

The image should explain itself.

The table basicly is repeating the whole table for each results instead of displaying the results with multiple lines on one table, its doing 1 line on 1 table many times.

[image]

Here's the code that involves it-

```
<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
    $f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
    $f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"date");
    $f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"agentclient");
    $f4=mysql_result($result,$i,"propertydescription");
    $f5=mysql_result($result,$i,"transactiontype");
    $f5=mysql_result($result,$i,"applicabledocument");
    $f5=mysql_result($result,$i,"received");
    $f5=mysql_result($result,$i,"paid");
?>

  <table width="98%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr valign="bottom" bgcolor="#000000">
      <td width="24"><span class="style1b"><strong>No.</strong></span></td>
      <td width="105"><span class="style1b"><strong>Date</strong></span></td>
      <td width="57"><span class="style1b"><strong>Agent/client</strong></span></td>
      <td width="170"><span class="style1b"><strong>Property/Description</strong></span></td>
      <td width="199"><span class="style1b"><strong>Transaction type </strong></span></td>
      <td width="235"><span class="style1b"><strong>Applicable document </strong></span></td>
      <td width="58"><span class="style1b"><strong>Received</strong></span></td>
      <td width="58"><span class="style1b"><strong>Paid</strong></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
      <td><?php echo $f1; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $f2; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $f3; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $f4; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $f5; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $f6; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $f7; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $f8; ?></td>
    </tr>
  </table>   



<?php
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of way to improve this code, but to fix your immediate problem, just take the header row out of the loop:

```
      <table width="98%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
        <tr valign="bottom" bgcolor="#000000">
          <td width="24"><span class="style1b"><strong>No.</strong></span></td>
          <td width="105"><span class="style1b"><strong>Date</strong></span></td>
          <td width="57"><span class="style1b"><strong>Agent/client</strong></span></td>
          <td width="170"><span class="style1b"><strong>Property/Description</strong></span></td>
          <td width="199"><span class="style1b"><strong>Transaction type </strong></span></td>
          <td width="235"><span class="style1b"><strong>Applicable document </strong></span></td>
          <td width="58"><span class="style1b"><strong>Received</strong></span></td>
          <td width="58"><span class="style1b"><strong>Paid</strong></span></td>
        </tr>
<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
$f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"date");
$f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"agentclient");
$f4=mysql_result($result,$i,"propertydescription");
$f5=mysql_result($result,$i,"transactiontype");
$f5=mysql_result($result,$i,"applicabledocument");
$f5=mysql_result($result,$i,"received");
$f5=mysql_result($result,$i,"paid");

?>
                <tr valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                  <td><?php echo $f1; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $f2; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $f3; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $f4; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $f5; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $f6; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $f7; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $f8; ?></td>
                </tr>    

              <?php
$i++;
}
?>
              </table>
```